# Pixel perfect icons, how to

Tags: icon, pixel

I use Inkscape to create icons. And I see that Font Awesome talks about their icons being `pixel perfect`. I like the idea and always tried to do the same with the default canvas which is A4. But when I have to use it on a 48px or 64px ( etc ) icon templates ( built-in in Inkscape ) I see that `pixel perfect` is no longer valid with the icon. ie, when I try to fit the icon in the 64x64 px template it loses the pixel perfection it had while I drew it in an A4 sized canvas.

What is your method of avoiding this ? I find it hard to generate ideas on a 48x48 or 64x64 px canvas. It is easier to try different things until we reach the final product when we have space on the canvas.

Comment: To make things pixel perfect, use the final canvas size that you're going to export from the start

Comment: May I know what final canvas size should be if we going to make an icon pack like Font Awesome ? Thanks.

Comment: I think their website can help you more than I can.